# In which ways can nginx send a request to my app server?

Tags: nginx

I know it can go to a local port with proxy_pass, and there's also stuff like FastCGI and wsgi. Is there a list of these ways nginx can send requests to my server?

Comment: You could take a look at the [list of directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for any which end with `_pass`.

Comment: @RichardSmith ty